# using emberjs history location api with router fails with undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

The jsbin below works and the hashbang url  changes just fine, when clicking on links.

You can live preview it here:

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aqifug/1/)

[jsbin code view](http://jsbin.com/aqifug/1/edit)

When I add code to thesame jsbin, in order to use emberjs history location, the url doesn’t change and it fails with undefined. See the new jsbin for that:

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aqifug/2/edit)

Just scroll 3/4 way down to see where I added:

```
 EmBlog.Router.reopen({
    location: ‘history’
  });
```

This also failed:

```
 EmBlog.Router.reopen({
    location: 'history',
    rootURL: '/'
 });
```

This is the whole router:

```
  EmBlog.Router.map(function() {
     this.resource("posts", function(){
     this.route('new');
     this.route('show', {path: '/:post_id'}) ;
     this.route('edit', {path: '/:post_id/edit'});
     });
  });
```

For instance, clicking on the post link below, doesn't change the URL but it only displays the content in the posts template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">


     <li> {{#linkTo "index"}} Home {{/linkTo}} </li>        
     <li> {{#linkTo 'posts'}} Post {{/linkTo}} </li>  

     <div> {{outlet}}</div>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, the problem is with the jsbin url. You would need to set the `/:sha/:id/edit/` when you change the baseUrl when you reopen the router

```
EmBlog.Router.reopen({
    location: 'history',
    rootURL: '/aqifug/6/edit/'
 });
```

I had a few other issues with your code. One was with ember-data. I just changed it to the latest [ember build](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-0.13.js). And the needs for commentNew also wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I presume that this is your updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aqifug/4/edit ) since it has the latest ember-data. It still doesn't work with location history, even when I use **rootURL: '/aqifug/6/edit/'**.  This doesn't run even outside jsbin. On my dev machine, it has a Rails backend, from where I extracted the emberjs code to jsbin to enable me show the code related to the question. Even on the dev machine with  rails backend, the **history location** doesn't work. So it might not only be a jsbin issue. Thanks